# First Table of Random Numbers

Tags: ho.history-overview, st.statistics, pr.probability

What was the first table of random numbers of any sort?

The best I can do is Tippett and Pearson's Random Sampling Numbers of 1927.

Can anybody identify an earlier table?

Thanks for any insight.

Cheers, Scott

Comment: The review by C R Rao of the book, The Making of Statisticians (edited by J. Gani), says of that 1927 book, "Such a book could not have been published before the twentieth century when scientific theories were conceived in a deterministic framework." 

Comment: If you don't get answers here at MO (say, in the next few days), you might want to post your question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/ , making sure you provide links from one question to another.

Answer (score 4):

Erastus De Forest's 1876 [booklet](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000439114) on *Interpolation and Adjustment of Series* has an early table of random numbers on page 18, or in columns (5) and (6) of the below. Stephen Stigler's [article](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1177011943) on *Stochastic Simulation in the 19th Century* discusses this, and also work by George Darwin, Francis Galton, and William Gosset.

[image]